Why can't we use Metropolis-Hastings in mini-batch settings?
I have seen papers such as Stochastic gradient Langevin dynamics (link) and Stochastic gradient Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo (link) which could be used to train EBM models (in the log-likelihood context where these methods could be used to estimate the expectation term that requires sampling from the model itself).
Why can't we use Metropolis-Hastings in mini-batch settings? Why do we need to iterate over the whole dataset to generate a single sample from the EBM in MH context?
I highly appreciate your answer.
